# allocating memory on stack is bigger when disassembling code

Tags: c++, c, disassembly

I have the following code. I expected the size of the stack in main function to be 8 bytes on 64 bit system, but when disassembling I see strange thing: it is 16. I am using https://godbolt.org/ x86-64 GCC 9.3. So my question is why?

```
#include <memory>

struct my_struct {
    char a[10];
    int b;
    char c;
    short d;
};

int main() {
    struct my_struct* s = (struct my_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(s));
    return 0;
}
```

```
.LC0:
        .string "%lu\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     edi, 20
        call    malloc
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     esi, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: It is all about [Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). For Intel it is 16 byte.

Comment: Check [-mstackrealignx](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) command line option doc. `Realign the stack at entry. On the x86, the -mstackrealign option generates an alternate prologue and epilogue that realigns the run-time stack if necessary. This supports mixing legacy codes that keep 4-byte stack alignment with modern codes that keep 16-byte stack alignment for SSE compatibility.`